# how to ensure and get window handle by its name represented in UNICODE?

Tags: c, winapi

how can i make sure that when i transfer Minesweeper it will be in unicode and not will be casted to ASCII?

```
HWND procHnd;
HWND windowHnd=FindWindow(NULL,"Minesweeper");
```

does it matter at all the name of the process or window representation?

Comment: Note that the "Unicodeness or not" of the other window is irrelevant. All strings internally in Windows are unicode and the A API calls just convert to and from unicode using the current codepage before calling the W version. The end result is that it will only matter if the window has a title that can't be represented in the current codepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly use the Unicode version of the API

```
HWND windowHnd = FindWindowW(NULL, L"Minesweeper");
```

You are currently building your application for ANSI characters. If you want to use Unicode throughout you should change your project options to use Unicode. If you did that you can simply write it as

```
HWND windowHnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Minesweeper");
```

Windows API functions that have parameters which contain text are available in two versions, an ANSI version and a Unicode version. For example the user32 DLL does not export a function called `FindWindow`. Instead it exports `FindWindowA`, the ANSI version, and `FindWindowW`, the Unicode version. Macros in the Windows header files convert `FindWindow` into either `FindWindowA` or `FindWindowW`, depending on which character set you target.

In Visual Studio you can set this option in the project configuration under Configuration Properties | General | Character Set. Select *Use Unicode Character Set*.

Comment: that what i tried but when i do it i get
ERROR : argument of type"const wchar_t*" is incompatibale with the parameter of type "LPCSTR"

Comment: You will get that error if you call the ANSI version `FindWindowA`. Call the Unicode version `FindWindowW`.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the function name?

Comment: ok thanks so by default the winapi works in ansi, and if i want to do it UNICODE i have to do it explicity, right?

Comment: No, you can set a couple of conditional defines to get the UNICODE APIs by default. I didn't say how to do that because you didn't say which compiler you used. Are you using Visual Studio.

Comment: OK, don't know about wingw, but I've added a bit about VS. I'm sure you can look up what wingw does in their help. Ultimately this is just a shortcut for defining the `_UNICODE` conditional which is what the header file macros use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516728/how-to-defualtly-define-all-the-winapi-windows-to-treat-strings-as-unicode. i opened another post if someone will look for it in google.