# how to defualtly define all the winapi to treat strings as UNICODE?

Tags: c, winapi

Using visual studio, is there a way to define all the function of the winapi to treat all the strings as UNICODE?

Comment: The Windows API cannot turn your strings into Unicode.  You'll have to declare them wchar_t[] instead of char[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `L` prefix for all your Unicode strings. A non-prefixed string, e.g. `"hello"`, is always a `char` based string. There is no shortcut in the language that would treat such a string as a wide character string.

Answer (score 2):

The MS libraries are organized by macros.

- Use the name of the API methods without the appende "A" or "W".
- Wrap your string definitions in _T() macro.

By doing this way defining "_UNICODE" in Preprocessor will build unicode build.

```
CreateFile(_T("C:\out.txt"),GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
```

will resove to:

```
// _UNICODE defined
CreateFileW(L"C:\out.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
```

or

```
// _UNICODE not defined
CreateFileA("C:\out.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
```

Comment: `_T` only makes sense if you intend to build ANSI versions of your code. And that only makes sense if you need to target Windows 9x. Otherwise your code becomes rather unreadable.

Comment: I would also normally use the L but if you use the L you should also use the W postfix.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to define `_UNICODE`, use `L` and not use the `W` prefix and just regard Win32 as a Unicode API.

Comment: Its perfectly fine if you are working in a homogene infrastructure and you are not doing any inheader implementations for utilities ...

Answer (score 1):

When you set your project to compile for Unicode all WinAPI functions will take Unicode strings (if there are unicode function equivalents). However when you specify a string literal in C++ it is by default char* so in order to create Unicode string literals you need to either specify them with the prefix `L` or use the macro `_T( "mystring" )` (Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this: Project->MyProject Properties->Configuration Properties. Set **Character Set** to **Use Unicode Character Set**. That essentially makes your project a unicode one, and all functions now expect unidoe.

Make sure that you *carefully* review your source after such a wide change.