# I am very confused about this error (LPCWSTR)

Tags: c++

I'm writing a class library for injection, and I have received an error from the compiler as follows:

> ‘HWND FindWindowW(LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char *'

```cpp
wnd_handle = FindWindow(nullptr, window_name);
if (!wnd_handle) return false;
```

Comment: You've provided one line of code totally out of context that uses a variable not declared in that code. Please see [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516449/how-to-ensure-and-get-window-handle-by-its-name-represented-in-unicode/8516481

Answer (score 3):

The Windows API sometimes provides multiple versions of the same function. For the *FindWindow* function there is:

```
    HWND FindWindowA(LPCSTR lpClassName, LPCSTR lpWindowName);
    HWND FindWindowW(LPCWSTR lpClassName, LPCWSTR lpWindowName);
```

The [*LPCSTR*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/f8d4fe46-6be8-44c9-8823-615a21d17a61) type used by [*FindWindowA*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) equates to "const char*" so calling *FindWindowA* with the parameters you were using should resolve your issue.

On the otherhand, if you want to work with [*FindWindowW*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww), know that [*LPCWSTR*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/76f10dd8-699d-45e6-a53c-5aefc586da20) refers to "const wchar_t*" and *wchar_t* is a larger data type than *char*.

```
    wchar_t* winClass = L"WindowClass";
    wchar_t* winName = L"WindowName";

    HWND wnd_handle = FindWindowW(winClass, winName);
    if(!wnd_handle)
        return false;
```

Note: the "L" in the code above signifies that this is a wide-character string, not a *char*-based string.

Comment: Just added links using a new technique.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that FindWindow is a macro that resolves to FindWindowA or FindWindowW depending on the UNICODE macro definition.  In the same way, LPCTSTR resolves to LPCSTR or LPCWSTR and TEXT() will resolve to "" or L"" so you can write code without knowing whether it is unicode or not.  Here is some documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings